# Nodemon : node not running

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I've create my first node application with a `server.js` file.

When I make this :
`nodemon ./server.js localhost 3000`

I get these messages but the website on `http://localhost:3000` is not running.

> [nodemon] 1.18.10 [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
>
> [nodemon] watching: *.* [nodemon] starting `node ./server.js localhost
>
> 3000` [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart

What am I doing wrong?

`server.js` file :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

const multipartMiddleware = multipart();

cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: 'aaa',
    api_key: 'xxx',
    api_secret: 'xxxxxdd'
});

app.post('/upload', multipartMiddleware, function(req, res) {
  cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.files.image.path,
    {
      ocr: "adv_ocr"
    }, function(error, result) {
        if( result.info.ocr.adv_ocr.status === "complete" ) {
          res.json(result); // result.info.ocr.adv_ocr.data[0].textAnnotations[0].description (more specific)
        }
    });
});
```

I'm trying to test with postman by make a post request but I get : `Could not get any response`

Comment: Did you run ```npm install``` prior to start your app?
You need to ensure that the dependencies you are using are downloaded and installed prior to run the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an `app.listen` line to your code so that the program stays running and listening for requests. Currently node just runs the file and since there is nothing keeping the program running by the end of the file, the program exits immediately.

You can add a line like this to the bottom of your file:

```js
const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening for requests on port ${port}`));
```

Then just run the file with:

```
nodemon ./server.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Your server.js file ends and thus you get a clean exit message from node.What you need to do is to add the following lines of code at the end of server.js. You need the app to always listen to port 3000. I'm posting all the the server.js file.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

const multipartMiddleware = multipart();

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: 'aaa',
  api_key: 'xxx',
  api_secret: 'xxxxxdd'
});

app.post('/upload', multipartMiddleware, function(req, res) {
  cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.files.image.path,
  {
    ocr: "adv_ocr"
  }, function(error, result) {
      if( result.info.ocr.adv_ocr.status === "complete" ) {
        res.json(result); //    result.info.ocr.adv_ocr.data[0].textAnnotations[0].description (more specific)
    }
  });
});

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening in port ${port}...`));
```

And now you can run your code with nodemon server.js only

Comment: I've add the server.js file